# One character is coming in next line

Tags: jasper-reports

Some attribute character is coming in the next line.it should come in one line

Example:

Student looking like

```
Student
```

but name is looking like

```
nam
e
```

The code is

```xml
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="21" uuid="e3b2f0ba-d810-42d5-aad6-74b440e871c6"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: Did you try to increase textField's width?

Comment: Are you using ireport or jasperstudio? If no, then pls make use of it. You can easily create reports. :)